# oracle epm1121 configure web server failed because of missing ohs_component

Tags: oracle

When installing epm1121 to linux redhat 5, installation of EPM1121 success.

But during the configuration, **'configure web server'** failed.

1. Checked the log which from below path

   > MIDDLEWARE_HOME/user_projects/epmsystem1/httpConfig/ohs/diagnostics/logs/OPMN

   written failed message MIDDLEWARE_HOME/user_projects/epmsystem1/httpConfig/ohs/config/**OHS/ohs_component/httpd.conf**
   wasn't found

Have checked the directory, it only has

```
    >MIDDLEWARE_HOME/user_projects/epmsystem1/httpConfig/ohs/config/OPMN/opmn
```

The folder OHS/ohs_components with its embedded files are none exists.

Summary:

- Even official website mentioned if en-counter this prob should find what dir to watch log, but after checked the log and know the reason, should how to take action to solve this prob?
- The missing /OHS/ohs_component with its file where to find it?

The problem resolved, **as some of reader not understand the solution** relate to this problem. I will explain more details.

For Q1, after you read enough hyperion logs, you will know hyperion installer need use your /etc/hosts hostname and IP address to create file to that machine. My case is wrong IP provided, hyperion installer failed to find the correct virtual machine and create ohs_component files.

For Q2. once you correct the wrong IP address. Re-run your ./configtool.sh it will copy your installed ohs things to the provided IP machine folder xxxx/OHS/ohs_component/

If need more details how solved this problem can reference my oralce community detailed question track.  Please refer this link: [Failed Configure Web Server because missing ohs_component, how to resolve it?](https://community.oracle.com/message/12760920)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this problem by finding out local host name is not consist with its IP address. After correcting the IP Address, the problem resolved.

Another point need focus is your user account which used to install Hyperion better join the root, or else may not satisfied some required right.

The other important need care is your .bash_profile need adding below configuration.

[image]